# Adding custom style to a Wiki page using MarkDown in Gitlab

Tags: css, gitlab, markdown, wiki

I’m trying to reproduce this example https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/product/technical-writing/markdown-guide/#styles 95

I’m writing this block in the content of the page

```
<style>
.purple {
  color:inherit;
}

.purple:hover {
  color:rgb(107,79,187);
}
</style>
```

Hey! Hover the cursor over me and guess what?

```
{: .purple}
```

But when I go to the content preview it doesn’t work.

What I’m doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page that you linked to](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/#styles) is about how markdown works for [GitLab's handbook](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook) which is built using a Static Site Generator that will interpret those style tags.

For any markdown styling within the GitLab product, including the wiki, you want to refer to the [GitLab Flavored Markdown documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html).